# What is PICK_CONTACT argument in startActivityForResult function?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I have an Android Dialer App in which I want to open contacts. I took the code from Stack Overflow itself. But there is an argument in the `startActivityForResult` function, `PICK_CONTACT`. It is showing error.

```
    else if(id == R.id.action_contacts){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);

    }
```

And the on `ActivityResult` function is like this

```
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    // TODO Fetch other Contact details as you want to use

                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Please help how to correct this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a request code. When calling `startActivityForResult`, you need to pass in an argument that identifies your request. This same integer value is used later on in `onActivityResult` to check which request you are returning from.

You should declare this, and any other request codes like this at the top of your activity.

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1; // requestCode for Contact Picker intent
```

More details can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html